# bug in php armstrong code

Tags: php, math

I am just a beginner in php. I have tried to write code for armstrong numbers. I have checked my code by 153. The output of my code is 0.153is not an armstrong number.How can i correct it? Here is my code.

```
<?php
$n=153;
while($n>1)
{
    $b=$n%10;
    $c=$b*$b*$b;
    $n=$n/10;
    $d=$c+$d;
}
if($d==$n)
    echo $n."is an armstrong number";
else
    echo $n."is not an armstrong number";
?>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't implement integer division with integer result and ignoring the reminder as C does. `$n=$n/10;` produces a floating point value and from that point the code is out of track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `$n` inside your loop and use it for comparison (`$d==$n`) and output afterwards. Make a copy of `$n`'s value and use that instead in your loop.

*Remark:* Your loop should test for `$n>0` instead of `$n>1`.

Answer (score 2):

Given the [Armstrong Numbers definition](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html), a functional solution is more concise and a little bit clearer to me

```
function isArmstrongNumber($number) {
    $digits=str_split($number); // create an array containing the digit into the
    $result = array_sum(
        array_map(
            function($x){return $x*$x*$x;},
            $digit
        )
    );
    return $number == $result;
}
```

It turns out that the previous definition was valid for number of three digits.
A [general definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) lead to a
slight different function:

```
function isArmstrongNumber($number) {
    $digits=str_split($number); // create an array containing the single digits
    $power= count($digits);     // the power every digit has to be raised to
    $result = array_sum(
        array_map('pow', $digits, array_fill(0,$power,$power))
    );
    return $number == $result;
}
```

You can use the code in this way:

```
$candidate = 153;
if(isArmstrongNumber($candidate) {
    /* armstrong number */
    echo $candidate, ' is an Armstrong number.';
} else {
    /* not armstrong number */
    echo $candidate, ' is not an Armstrong number.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num    = 371;
$sum    = 0;
$temp   = $num;
while($temp!= 0){
    $rem    =   $temp%10;
    $sum    =   $sum+($rem*$rem*$rem); 
    $temp   =   $temp/10;

}
if($num == $sum){
   echo "Armstrong number"; 
}
else{
   echo  "not an armstrong number";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$n=407;
 $x =(string)$n;
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($x);$i++)
 { 
    $num+=$x[$i]*$x[$i]*$x[$i];


 }
if($n==$num){
  echo $num.'is a palindrome';
}else{
  echo $num.'is Not a palindrome';

}
```

Comment: This is simplest way to find armstrong number for  three digit

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$n = 153;
$tempN = $n;

while($tempN > 0) {
    $remainder = $tempN % 10;
    $sum = $sum + $remainder * $remainder * $remainder;
    $tempN = $tempN / 10;
}

if($n == $sum) {
    /* armstrong number */
} else {
    /* not armstrong number */
}
?>
```

Comment: This code suffers from the same error as the original one. Please see my answer.

Comment: At where i can see the answer?

Comment: This post is the answer, or at least the fixed code (with the suggestion of Howard).

Comment: 153 is an armstrong number. But the code dispalys 153 is not an armstrong number.

Comment: Haven't tested this, but it is converted from a C implementation - see http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-find-armstrong-number

Answer (score 0):

The program you posted in the question looks like being translated from C. PHP provides easy ways to work with strings and arrays; they can be used to split the number in digits and apply transformations to each digit.

This is how a PHP solution could look like:

```
function isArmstrongNumber($number)
{
    // The power is not always 3 but the number of digits of the number
    $power = strlen($number);

    // Compute the sum of values returned by array_map()
    $sum = array_sum(
        array_map(
            // Apply this function to each digit
            function ($digit) use ($power) {
                // Compute $digit to the power of $power
                return $digit ** $power;
            },
            // Split the number into digits
            str_split($number)
        )
    );

    return $sum === $number;
}
```

The [exponentiator operator (`**`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) is available since PHP 5.6. For older versions, the [`pow()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function can be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

**you can check if any number is amstrong or not**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['log']))
{
    echo $limit=$_POST['limit'];
    amstrong_checker($limit);
}
function amstrong_checker($val){// $val take value from user.
  $value=$val; 
  $counter=0; 
  $amstrong=0;
  while($val >= 1){
    $digit[$counter]=$val%10;
    $val = $val/10;
    $counter=$counter+1; //count the digits of a value.
  }
  for($i=0 ; $i<$counter ; $i++){
    $data=1;
    for($j=0 ; $j<$counter ; $j++){
      $data=$data * $digit[$i]; //calculate according to digits count.
    }
    $amstrong=$amstrong+$data;//calculate sum of total. 
  }
  if($amstrong==$value){ //checking.
    echo 'amstrong number';
  }
  else{
    echo 'not a amstrong number';
  }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<body>
 <form method="post" >
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>limit</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="limit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="log" type="submit"  value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: The above mentioned code is used for check any number is amstrong or not.

Comment: You should explain your code. in the answer. Explain why it works, or if it uses some well known method, mention that

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$armnum2 = 407;
$total3 = 0;
for ($x3 = $armnum2; $x3 != 0; $x3 = ( int ) $x3 / 10) {
     $rem3 = (int) $x3 % 10;
     $total3 = $total3 + $rem3 * $rem3 * $rem3;
 }
 if ($armnum2 == $total3) {
   echo "Yes, Number $armnum2 is an Armstrong number";
 } else {
echo "No, Number $armnum2 it is not an Armstrong number";
}
?>

 Output:

 Yes, Number 407 is an Armstrong number
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.